# java generics and reflection,why different result

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Test test = new Test() {};
there's nothing in {},why the result is different.

```
public class Test<T> {
    private final TypeToken<T> typeToken = new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) {};
    private final Type type = typeToken.getType();

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(this.type);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<Integer> test = new Test<Integer>() {};
        Test<Integer> test2 = new Test<Integer>();
        test.foo();// class java.lang.Integer
        test2.foo();//T
    }
}
```

Comment: What result? How is it different? Note that in one case you're creating an instance of `Test` and in the other you're creating an instance of an anonymous subclass of `Test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is different because when you write this

```
Test test = new Test() {};
```

you instruct the compiler to create a new anonymous type for you. The type derives from `Test`, and can (but does not have to) override its methods.

In your case the type does not override any methods, but it is a different type.

Comment: I don't understand what point you're trying to make with the _override its methods_. Can you clarify?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OP's confusion comes from not understanding the syntax for creating anonymous classes with curly braces after `new` expression, that do not provide any new behavior, i.e. when there's nothing inside curly braces. I am trying to make a point that usually you place your method overrides inside these curly braces, but Java syntax allows you to inherit the base class with no further specialization.

Comment: I don't think their confusion is about general anonymous classes. I think they're confusion is about the `TypeToken` behavior returning the type argument for the anonymous class instance and the type parameter `T` for the other.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It was my interpretation of the first sentence of the question. To me, it sounded that OP expected the result to be the same, because the two declarations differed "only" in a pair of curly braces at the end, with "nothing in [them]". Hence, I suspected that the fact that he's creating a new type did not quite register with OP.

Comment: Sure, but how does that _new type_ affect the result (_why the result is different_)? And what does overriding methods (or not overriding methods) have to do with it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Once OP understood it's a new type, he figured out the rest. Overriding methods is what you usually do when you create an anonymous type. *Not* overriding methods in an anonymous type is an exception, rather than the rule. To many newcomers, empty curly braces are completely divorced from anonymous types. They are "just syntax," which "needs to be written that way." This is similar to "double brace initialization": some programmers believe it's a special initialization syntax, rather than a combo of an anonymous type and an initializer block.